# Connecting custom webapp's user base with that of Business Catalyst's user base

Tags: adobe, business-catalyst

I am working on a web (browser based) application where the website (homepage and other marketing pages) is to be created using Adobe Business Catalyst and the platform (the actual application) is created in-house.
The platform application includes the following :

- has its own user base
- OAuth 2.0 server
- authorized Rest APIs
- HTML 5.0 client webapp

Now, Adobe Business Catalyst has its own user base which will manage user sign up and sign in functionality.

How can I join Adobe BC's user base with my platform's user base (for e.g. the moment a user registers in Adobe BC, I want it to be added into my app's user database)?

I also want a way to sync the login between Adobe BC and my personal application.

Answer (score 0):

As you have REST API on your platform application, you can do it by creating an external integration app. This app can sync user base with [Customer BC API](https://docs.worldsecuresystems.com/reference/rest-apis/customers/customers.html)

For the other way round you can send ajax post to external app when user registers on BC website that will sync data to your platform application.